# What is the Django HOST_DOMAIN setting for?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

Despite googling I can't find any documentation for the Django HOST_DOMAIN setting in the settings.py.

I am going through a settings.py file I have been given and this is the only part of the file I am not 100% clear on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out what are all the *django specific* settings at [the settings reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/) which lists all the settings variables (and their defaults) that are set by django.

Since `settings.py` is just any other Python module, you are free to define your own variables and import them in your code with:

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.MY_CUSTOM_SETTING
```

Third party applications can also define their own settings, which you can modify by entering the specific value in `settings.py`.

It sounds like `HOST_DOMAIN` is one such custom setting.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a Django setting.

It's perfectly good practice to define your own project-specific settings inside settings.py, and that is presumably what the original developer did here.